# Summing over Prime Factors (without repetition)

Tags: summation, number-theory, code-request, prime-numbers, mathworld

Wolfram Mathworld (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofPrimeFactors.html) describes a function sopfr(n), the sum of prime factors, which I currently need. This code doesn't work when I insert it in Mathematica. I want a version of this code that does not do repetition. So, e.g., the output for $20=2^25$ would be $2+5$ and *not* $2+2+5$.

Given $n$, and $j\le n,$ I am requesting a code for the that gives output
 $$\sum_{p\le n, p\,\text{prime factor of } j}p\,.$$

when the input is $n,j$. So here I do not get the entire sum of prime factors, only those bounded by some prescribed $n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: I think you meant "bounded by some prescribed j", not by some n.

```
FactorInteger[11!]
```

(* {{2, 8}, {3, 4}, {5, 2}, {7, 1}, {11, 1}} *)

```
Map[First, FactorInteger[11!]]
```

(* {2, 3, 5, 7, 11} *)

```
sopfr[n_, j_] := Select[Map[First, FactorInteger[n]], # < j &];
sopfr[11!, 8]
```

(* {2, 3, 5, 7} *)

```
sopfr[n_, j_] := Total[Select[Map[First, FactorInteger[n]], # < j &]];
sopfr[11!, 8]
```

(* 17 *)

Try to understand the thinking that must have been behind each step of this as it was written. That you will be able to make use of for the next problem.

Comment: You are correct, there's no need to even mention $n$ here. I am asking for a sum of the prime divisors of $j$. In this case, 3,5,7 don't divide $j=8$, so i wouldn't include those in the sum.

Comment: I think I've found what I want:    sopfr[n_] := Total[Select[Map[First, FactorInteger[n]]]];Total[sopfr[10]].  When I don't insert total, it just gives a table, but the Total gives the desired sum.

Comment: @The Substitute I'm a little confused. I thought your question was "Give me the total of the prime factors of n that are less than j." If you are trying to modify my example to eliminate the "less than j" part then perhaps this will do: `sopfr[j_]:=Total[Map[First,FactorInteger[j]]];sopfr[10]`